# How to Check if Bitmap is null

Tags: c#, bitmap

I'm getting "Parameter is not valid Exception". Here if my code

```
bp = new Bitmap(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height); //Set Screen Size 
Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bp);
gr.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(bp.Width, bp.Height),CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
```

Comment: *Where* do you get the exception? Post the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more I can't give a 100% answer, but you should be checking for null values. Something like:

```
bp = new Bitmap(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height); //Set Screen Size 
Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bp);
if (gr != null)
{
    gr.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(bp.Width, bp.Height),CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
}
```

Most likely you are getting a null object and trying to reference a property within it. You can't do that, thus the null reference exception. I'm not saying the above code is exactly what you need, but in general if you don't know for sure that the object you're trying to use has populated values, you should be null checking.

Comment: The ctor will not return null, it will either return a new instance or throw.

Comment: Im  geting null when screen width and height is setting to bitmap object

Comment: So, save the screen dimensions in int variables and debug through it. See what they contain.